# Count words for each author separately

Tags: posts

We pay for authors as (price-for-word). Currently, we save a custom field (added manually by author with his words count) within the post for each author to calculate the number of words he has written in all posts.

Therefore, we would like to do this more easily by calculating the number of words for each author separately, considering that one post may be modified by more than one author.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/360742/edit) to add in the relevant code. Also: what is the relationship between the "post[s]" and the "topic[s]"?

Comment: sorry, currently we just get the field saved by author to count his words.